# which one to choose between ( PVC & ConfigMap )

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pvc

since this morning i've a question in my mind. 
What is the best things to manage file configuration on kubernetes!

For the moment we use `PVC & PV`

But i would want to update **automatically** during the **CI pipeline** the config files . For one application we have almost **10 configs files**

How can i update it automatically with kubernetes ? 
Or do you think i will have to change for configMap ?

I still reading the documentation on internet but i dont find an answear to my question :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If it is configuration then a ConfigMap fits. You can update the ConfigMap resource descriptor file as part of your CI pipeline and then apply that change with 'kubectl apply' and you can do a rolling update on your app. This moves you in the direction of every config change being a tracked and versioned change.

You may also want to look at Secrets, depending on how sensitive your config is.

I guess you will have the same number of files whether in a PV or a ConfigMap - the choice only affects how they are made available to the app in Kubernetes. But if you find your CI pipelines are doing a lot of replacements then a templating system could help. I'd suggest looking at helm so that you can pass parameters into your deployments at the time of deploy.

Comment: we use helm to deploy. So i going to continue to readsome documentation on configMap.

Comment: Cool, might be worth you looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47595295/how-do-i-load-multiple-templated-config-files-into-a-helm-chart as seems like your scenario is very similar