# Spring boot app dont reading values from 2nd file in configmap

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-kubernetes

We are using `implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-config:2.1.1")`.

For configmap used 2 files:
`application.yaml|yml`,
`application-parent.yaml|yml`.

```
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.application }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
data:
  application.yml: |
  {{ (.Files.Glob "config/application.yaml").AsConfig | indent 2 }}
  application-dev.yml: |
  {{ (.Files.Glob "config/application-parent.yaml").AsConfig | indent 2 }}
```

After successful deploy and startup application reading values from `application.yml`, but ignoring values from `application-parent.yml`.

[k8s console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUjeK.png)

What can i do wrong?

Comment: I think it is supposed to be one Files.Glob per name.  So in this case application takes the first Files.Glob.

You could llok into using range and see if that helps.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47595295/how-do-i-load-multiple-templated-config-files-into-a-helm-chart

Comment: @SMA, i tried with key:path way and your way, but if config dont matching `application.yml` (for example APPLICATION-DEV.YAML, APPLICATION-parent.YAML`, app just ignores it and fails after startup (cause needed for success props lays in parent).