# multiple configMap files in Helm

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-helm

Somehow I cannot load environment variables and I have the following error when the pod starts:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
```

The structure of my Helm chart:

[image]

I have the following configuration in the configmap.yaml Helm template:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.nameOverride }}-config
data:
  application.yaml: {{ tpl (.Files.Get "files/application.yaml") . | quote }}
  appdynamicscontrollerconfig.yaml: {{ tpl (.Files.Get "files/appdynamics-controller-config.yaml") . | quote }}
  javaconfigmap.yaml: {{ tpl (.Files.Get "files/java-config-map.yaml") . | quote }}
```

The deployment.yaml Helm template:

```
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Values.nameOverride }}
          env:
            - name: APPLICATION
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: {{ .Values.nameOverride }}-config
                  key: application.yaml
            - name: APPDYNAMICS_CONTROLLER_CONFIG
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: {{ .Values.nameOverride }}-config
                  key: appdynamicscontrollerconfig.yaml
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: {{ .Values.nameOverride }}-config
                  key: javaconfigmap.yaml
```

```
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: {{ .Values.nameOverride }}-config
          items:
            - key: application.yaml
              path: application.yaml
            - key: appdynamicscontrollerconfig.yaml
              path: appdynamics-controller-config.yaml
            - key: javaconfigmap.yaml
              path: java-config-map.yaml
        name: {{ .Values.nameOverride }}-config
```

```
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /cs/app/config
              name: {{ .Values.nameOverride }}-config
              readOnly: true
```

Am I referencing incorrectly to the files which contain the environment variable?
Probably yes, but I couldn't find a documentation for it.

Comment: You are loading the contents of the files into environment variables (`valueFrom: { configMapRef: ... }`) and not using the mounted volume at all.  Do you need to set the environment variables to the mounted path name; `value: /cs/app/config/appication.yaml`?

Comment: (The ConfigMap setup you show isn't obviously related to the Java `ClassNotFoundException`.  Can you `docker run` your image successfully without Kubernetes; is your built application completely contained in the image?)

Comment: My application.yaml and the other config yaml files contain many vlaues. I would like to load the whole content of the file.
I cannot run docker local because of company policy, but in this case I don't think I need that, because I have an issue with the pod and not the container.
If I use
`envFrom:
            - configMapRef:
                name: java-config-map`
is working fine